# customer first name and last name separately (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, customer, session, customer-session

I am trying to get `First Name` and `Last Name` from the session.
But I am not able to get First name or last name.

Instead, I am able to get the full name.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');


$customer_name = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();  // gives me result
```

*But when I try to get first it returns null*

```
$customer_first_name = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getFirstName();  // gives me null
```

How to get the first name using `customerSession->getCustomer()`

Answer (score 2):

You should inject `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` in your construct :

```
protected $customerRepository;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository 
){
  $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}
public function getCustomerData()
{
  $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
  if($customer->getId()){
      echo $customer->getFirstname();
      echo $customer->getLastname();
  }
}
```

**Using Object Manager :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerRepository = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface::class);
$customer = $customerRepository->getById('your customer id');
if($customer->getId()){
    echo $customer->getFirstname();
    echo $customer->getLastname();

}
```